# how to add popup on google map with react leaflet?

Tags: reactjs

this is my code:

```js
<MapContainer center={position} style={{width:"100%",height:"600px"}} zoom={10} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    
  </MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always wrap it in a modal if you're just looking for it to pop over the page?

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Map Button
  </button>
```

then in your modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 modal_body_content">
              <p>Some contents...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 modal_body_map">
              <div class="location-map" id="location-map">
                <div style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" id="map_canvas">Your MapContainer here...</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 modal_body_end">
              <p>Else...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```